# Regex code to search multiline string in a text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to build a regex to find below multiline text in Notepad++ using

```
(*ANYCRLF)(SPIDs at the head of blocking chains)\n(spid)\n.\n[1-9]
```

But it only works till `SPID`. What expressions help it to find 20 characters of `-` and in the next line numbers (1-9). The text wasn't showing up properly.

The `spid` word is a constant and case sensitive. Only numerical values would be different but in the range of 1 to 9.

Matching text:

```
SPIDs at the head of blocking chains
spid                
-(dash) 20 times
               13257
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Please show us what the input text is, and then tell us what you are trying to match.  Do **not** paste image links please.

Comment: Sorry, just joined the forum. For some reason I am not able to post the sample text. Let me try again

Comment: Below is the text I am trying to find using regex-

SPIDs at the head of blocking chains
spid                
--------------------
               13257

Comment: Is `SPID` literal text, or is that just a placeholder for the values which are really there?  Please show us literal text.  And, do you want to consume until the _first_ `13257`, or until a later one?

Comment: The SPID is a constant and case sensitive. Only numerical values would be different and in the range of [1-9].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex `(*ANYCRLF)(SPIDs at the head of blocking chains)\n(spid)\n.\n[1-9]` you are matching `\n.\n` which will match a newline followed by any character and a newline. Instead of matching any character, you could match a dash 20 times `-{20}`.

You could update the last `\n` to `\s*` to match zero or more times a whitespace character and at the end match one or more times `[1-9]+`

[`(*ANYCRLF)(SPIDs at the head of blocking chains)\n(spid)\n-{20}\s+[1-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/1gGCQx/1)

Or instead of using `(*ANYCRLF)` and `\n` you might use `\s`:

[`\s*(SPIDs at the head of blocking chains)\s*(spid)\s*-{20}\s*[1-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/XCf2Gt/1/)

You use capturing groups `()` for `(SPIDs at the head of blocking chains)` and `(spid)` but if you only want to match the values you can omit the parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works very well in regex101 testing but when I try in notepad++ it says invalid expression and I can't find which operator needs to be replaced for it to work in Ultraedit or Notepad++

Comment: You can update `(*ANYCRLF)` to `\s*`. Try it with  [`\s*(SPIDs at the head of blocking chains)\s*(spid)\s*-{20}\s*[1-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/XCf2Gt/1)

Comment: that did it! Thank you again :)

Comment: I upvoted the downvote because I see no flaw in this answer.... and no reason from the downvoter